# Apache Http Client - Stop Removing Double Slashes from URL

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I am using Apache HTTP Components Client 4.5.7 to request a URL that containing a double slash. When I look at the wire log, I see that the double slash was "fixed" to be only one slash. Unfortunately that is no desireable behaviour for me, as it will cause the request to fail.

Background: I am requesting resized images from Thumbor (an image resize server). A Thumbor URL will basically look like this:

this url will cause thumbor to download http://host.com/image.jpg and resize it to fit into 200x200 pixels.

The code looks like this:

```
HttpGet httpUriRequest = new HttpGet("http://thumbors-server/usafe/200x200/http://host.com/image.jpg");
CLIENT.execute(httpUriRequest, responseHandler);
```

What httpclient sends to the server. however is this:

```
DEBUG o.a.h.headers     http-outgoing-1 >> GET /unsafe/300x300/http:/host.com/image1.jpg HTTP/1.1 
DEBUG o.a.h.headers     http-outgoing-1 >> Host: localhost:4002 
DEBUG o.a.h.headers     http-outgoing-1 >> Connection: Keep-Alive 
DEBUG o.a.h.headers     http-outgoing-1 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.7 (Java/11.0.1) 
DEBUG o.a.h.headers     http-outgoing-1 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

please note that http://host.com was replaced by http:/host.com (notice the missing second /). This will cause the request to fail.

How can I stop http client from "fixing" the url that I pass to it?

Answer (score 1):

For a similar case I encountered, the best solution was to use URLEncoder.encode to url-encode the embedded URL.

In your example,

```
new HttpGet("http://thumbors-server/usafe/200x200/" + URLEncoder.encode("http://host.com/image.jpg", "UTF-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this today in the http-client v4.5.13.  The server I'm hitting/testing does not handle URI's properly so URLEncoding didn't work.  I needed a workaround (short of using raw sockets) in my code.

After some debugging found that you can disable URI normalization using the RequestConfig.custom().setNormlizeUri() method when setting up the client configuration.

[Javadoc link to the RequestConfig builder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html)

Example:

```
requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeoutMS)
                    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(connectionTimeoutMS)
                    .setSocketTimeout(connectionTimeoutMS)
                    .setNormalizeUri(normalizeUri)
                    .build();
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem is in `URIUtils.rewriteURI()` where is this code:

```
final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(path.length());
boolean foundSlash = false;
for (int i = 0; i < path.length(); i++) {
    final char ch = path.charAt(i);
    if (ch != '/' || !foundSlash) {
        buf.append(ch);
    }
    foundSlash = ch == '/';
}
uribuilder.setPath(buf.toString());
```

So double slashes in uri path are always replaced with one slash. You can use another http client like *OkHttp* which doesn't make this normalization.

Comment: Does anyone know why they are doing it? What is the benefit?